# Multi store magento redirects to main store

Tags: magento-1.7, multistore, redirect

I need to create create another store, I am following the instructions on the Wiki magento but I can not work.

my problem is that when you enter the second store redirects me to the main store

eg. subdomain.mydomain.com
when I enter redirects me to mydomain.com

I also tried to create folder using just the second store, the url is displayed like mydomain.com/store2

but it shows me the home page of my main store

### Files:

## index.php

Last lines

```
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'knksvip';

/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

## .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)subdomain.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:knksvip]
```

### in store view Base URL Changed to

http://subdomain.mydomain.com/

Comment: Try to clean your cache

Comment: I'd be surprised if it were a cache issue. Its worth checking your domain alias settings, as sometimes they can be set to act as a 301 to the main domain.

Comment: before requesting help to you I checked the cache and is not the problem.

Comment: base url at least is correct?

Answer (score 3):

I have no clue how the mod_rewrite settings is working, but for us always worked:

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=storecode1
SetEnvIf Host www\.domain\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=storecode2
```

Comment: I am asking some info apart from your post, i am created multi-store, using http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-setup-multiple-website/. I am using the same theme for both stores, how can i change header and footer for my second store, pls keep in mind same theme. What is the use of symlinks?

Comment: Add a CMS block into both themes and have two different blocks added.

Comment: In localhost, what is your suggestion?

Comment: Add domains to your hosts file https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) and use local domains. Or directly use the TLD .localhost like: de.customer.localhost, en.customer.localhost (I'm not sure a subdomain works out of the box, so maybe you have to use en-customer.localhost)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Run store or run website */ $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';

 if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=="subdomain.mydomain.com") $mageRunCode="knksvip"; // <-- new line here

 Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

Chances are your .htaccess isn't passing the value.  This new line in your index.php will set your run code.

Comment: thanks for your help but still the same =(

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);` in `index.php` when using the subdomain?

Comment: var_dump not exist in index.php

i try it http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53970/magento-multi-store-with-domain-alias-404-error-on-2nd-store

but same problem, I'm going crazy

Comment: You mean it's returning NULL?

Comment: this is my index.php http://pastebin.com/WiR7JBqi

Comment: I meant add `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);exit();` so you can see what the variable is returning.  Also try to remove the line that you have here: `$mageRunType = 'website';`.  I've never had to mess with that for a multistore set up.

Comment: string(11) "mydomain.com"
deleted $mageRunType = 'website';

Comment: If you're getting `mydomain.com` when going to `subdomain.mydomain.com` then you need to add an A Record on your domain for `subdomain` that points to the same IP as your top level domain and don't just forward it.

Comment: ignore my last comment
I want to explain better

i have one folder, name folder is "vip", in this folder i pasted the files index.php and .htaccess

the files I've edited are those of this folder

I created a subdomain leading to the vip folder

when i go to vip.mydomain.com redirected to mydomain.com

but if i rename the index.php to index.php_OLD stop redirect me to main domain

i can look menssage (in vip.mydomain.com): 
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server. 

I think the problem is not the subdomain

Comment: So your subdomains are created as subfolders on your server.  In the index.php in your vip subfolder, change `Mage::run()` to `Mage::run('knksvip');`

Comment: you mean to replace this `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);` ?

no redirects me to the main domain but it shows me white page

Comment: What happens when you add `var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);exit();` to your vip/index.php and go to your subdomain?

Comment: NULL is white page
I asked my hosting believes me another subdomain to test without using the subfolder, ty for you help

Comment: In localhost, what is your suggestion?